# In PHP, what is the differences between NULL and setting a string to equal 2 single quotes

Tags: php, null

I used to set things like this when I wanted blank values.

```
$blankVar = '';
```

Then after some months, I decided this looked better and had a clearer intent.

```
$blankVar = null;
```

This worked without hiccup for a while, but recently with a PDO prepared statements I ran into a problem. Binding a value to null made the query fail, whilst binding it to '' did not. I needed to bind it to null, so that if a condition was met, it would insert blank data.

What are the differences between the 2? I still think equaling null (or at least a constant) looks better, so should I do this?

```
define('EMPTY', '');
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Null is just another datatype in PHP, which has only one value (null).**  Since PHP is a loosly typed language, it can be confusing how it handles different values.

`"", 0, "0", False, array(), Null` are all considered False in PHP.

Null, however, is a different kind of animal.  The **main** incompatibility with using Null is that you cannot tell if it isset().

```
$x = false;
isset($x)  ->  true
echo $x    ->  ""

$y = null;
isset($y)  ->  false
echo $y    ->  ""

//$z is not set
isset($z)  ->  false
echo $z    ->  E_NOTICE
```

So null is odd in the sense that it doesn't follow normal variable rules in PHP (at least some).  In most cases, it is fine.

**When it comes to database columns, PHP's NULL has no place there.**  You see, SQL is a string based language.  SQL's NULL must be represented by `NULL` with no quotes.

So if you want an EMPTY field, set it to ""

```
INSERT INTO foo SET bar = ""
```

But if you want a NULL field, set it to NULL

```
INSERT INTO foo SET bar = NULL
```

BIG DIFFERENCE.

But if you try to insert the PHP NULL directly, it will add zero characters to the query, (which leaves you with a blank or syntax error, depending on if you quoted it).

Comment: Thanks for including your section on SQL.

Comment: I'd use terminology that `""`, `0`, and `null` are *falsy* in PHP because if you use true equal operator, you'll find that e.g. `0 !== false`. Those are all false when casted to boolean context which is automatically done if you use operator `==` instead of `===`. This is similar to JavaScript behavior but the exact rules for casting are different. It's better to avoid using operator `==` in both languages and consider it a historical mishap that cannot be fixed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 23):

**null** is a special placeholder value in the programming language that literally means "nothing". It's not 0, it's not an empty string, it's nothing. There is no value in memory being pointed to. An empty string, on the other hand, is still a string object, just a very short one :)

Comment: If it is the clearest answer, and I agree, why did you not accept it?

Comment: @Chris: Because the one I accepted gave me more information.. I voted this one up instead.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that he says "It's not 0, it's not an empty string, it's nothing.". Yet, in PHP, (null == 0) is true. (null == "") as well. However, (null === 0) or (null === "") are false. While the answer is "good", it doesn't explain this VERY important distinction I had a problem with today!

Comment: This is very clear to me, it gives you the understanding on  when to set a variable to null or give it an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's one thing how nice each approach looks, but the main difference is that one is an empty string and the other is an uninitialized variable (null)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the differences stated by Rex, there's two types of comparisons in PHP, loose and strict:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

If strict comparisons or functions like is_null() are used in any capacity, you'll get different results. With loose comparisons, however, PHP is pretty lenient.

I don't know for sure, but you may be able to use your null approach, then just typecast when you're using the variable in the context where you had issues (i.e. pass (string) $blankVar). If that works, it may mean less changes are necessary to your code.

Comment: This looks useful, so if I continue to set things to null, and if I have a hiccup, simply $var = (string)$myPossiblyNullString; ?

Comment: PHP is weakly typed, so those sorts of things generally do work, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

'null' is the unique thing that uninitialized variables refer to. You can set a variable to refer to null. There is also the 'unset' state meaning the variable doesn't exist at all. You can check that via the [isset() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Most often used to check if an element of array exists and is, for example, a way to see if $_GET['op'] has received a querystring param. You can also make a variable unset (remove an element of an array) via the [unset() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). There is also a [function empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) which will check if a variable is either NULL, FALSE, 0, or an empty string