# diffrenece between $a=''; and $a=NULL; in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, what is the differences between NULL and setting a string to equal 2 single quotes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sing)

What does $a=''; indicates in php

and how $a=''; is different than $=NULL:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean $a = '' or $ a = ""

If so $a = "" or '' means that variable $a is being set equal to an empty string. In contrast $a = NULL means that variable $a is being set to a special PHP constant NULL which is effectively nothing. The major difference is that $a = '' sets $a as a string variable whereas $a = NULL doesn't. This tends to matter more in languages that require strict declaration of variable types.

See here for more info on NULL: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,But if i do like                        $a='';
$b=NULL;
if($a==$b)
echo 'variable Matches !';
else
echo 'No Match !';   that will give true.so can u give me some realistic example

Answer (score 1):

NULL is an unkown value, '' is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` indicates no value, it's like an unset variable. An empty string IS a value, and a variable containing an empty string IS defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = '';
echo '$a = \'\'';
var_dump( ($a == ''), ($a === ''), (is_null($a)) );

$a=null;
echo '$a = null';
var_dump( ($a == ''), ($a === ''), (is_null($a)) );
```

output:

```
$a = ''
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false
$a = null
boolean true
boolean false
boolean true
```