# Checking NULL against database record -> isset vs. is_null

Tags: php, mysql

I provided code, where first argument is path to image or default NULL in MySQL database,

```
function formatImage($img = NULL, $alt = NULL)
    {
        // if(isset($img)) DOESN'T WORK
        if(!$img == NULL)
        {
            return '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . $alt .'" />';
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Why isset doesn't work? Instead I have to check if is (!$img == NULL).

In case of using checking argument with isset, and that $img is NULL in database.  as output im getting whole HTML IMG tag with empty src attibutes, and alt attribute which is actaully title fetched from database.
Setting display property to none to images without src attribute isn't acceptable.

Comment: Define: `DOESN't WORK`

Comment: Perhaps `$img` ends up containing a string `'NULL'` - so his approach to using isset() didn't work out that well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a `var_dump($img)` just before the `if` will shed some light here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($img != NULL) {
    return '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . $alt .'" />';
}
```

**Explanation:**

If you compare `!$img` against `NULL` you basically do a boolean reversal on `$img` and then seeing if that compares to NULL - which is not what you want.

Also, please note that you should use

```
if($img !== NULL)
```

instead. `!=` will compare the values of the variables provided, while `!==` will compare the values AND the datatype (which in case of NULL might be your best interest).

Comment: Checking if variable is different with !img == NULL is only way I can have desired behaviour, if path in database == NULL outpur whole img tag, else return NULL.

Comment: If your database field is NULL then you will have no data to fill your image with. It looks to me as if you are confusing the expected return values here. If `$img` is set, then do something, otherwise return NULL. Anyway, i'd personally just go for a `if($img){}`

Answer (score 0):

After checking variable with var_dump, returned data from database is actually empty string,

```
string(0) "" and not `NULL` datatype and value literally.
```

That's why `isset()` keep returning TRUE in both cases. Using value checking works fine, because returned value is empty string not NULL data object, I mean type.

From [php.net](http://php.net) for return values of ISSET language construct:

***Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.***

Checking returned variable value and datatype against NULL would both evaluates to false, in case of `!==` true because datatype is NOT NULL as value IS NULL.

Seems that problem was in fact that I have expected NULL in database field behave as NULL data type.

Please correct me if I thinking wrong.

+1 @SquareCat

Comment: Sounds like it, yes. If you use `$img !== NULL` for comparison, it will work in your favour because it will also check the datatype. Make sure you don't have any occurrences of NULL as a string (`'NULL'`).

Comment: @SquareCat Field is default NULL in my database, and after retrieving, NULL appears as empty string "" in fetched array. Weird.

Comment: It is supposed to. NULL is basically a datatype. And a NULL in MySQL doesn't necessarily have to be the same as NULL in PHP, even though they mean the same. See [this thread] for details. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sin for)

Comment: @SquareCat, well, I didn't know that. I was knocked seeing isset evaluating TUE on NULL (without strings, ofcourse) fetched from database, later I've seen that is NULL represented as emtpy string.

Comment: `isset()` will check if the variable has been declared, regardless of its value.

Comment: @SquareCat Exactly. As I mentioned that's why it is evaluate to TRUE on empty string "" fetched from NULL field from my database. But that's another question.