# PHP returns NULL from database as empty string "". Why?

Tags: php, mysql

This could be connected to my previous question, and maybe a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341000/checking-null-against-database-record-isset-vs-is-null/20362471?noredirect=1#comment30463680_20362471).

Well, why value declared as `NULL` in MySQL database is returned as `""` (empty string), in this case all my functions which returns some value dependently on result of evaluation, dont' work.

```
$var = NULL; // false
$var = ""; // true
```

Also I'm dumping result of evaluating:

```
var_dump(isset($var));
```

I'm using PDO DB driver, PHP 5.4.7 and MySQL 5.5.27.

Is that like behaviour expected or is this some bug? NULL is saved in field as MySQL NULL, not string 'NULL'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$var === NULL` [would work better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1576273/477878).

Comment: Probably it's `NULL`, do you check this with `is_null()` or something else?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`is_null()`](http://www.php.net/is_null) to see if the value is null. `NULL` is equal to nothing. Even another `NULL`.

(Plus in your example you use an assignment operator (`=`) and not a comparison operator (`==` or `===`) but I am sure that is just a typo in your question).

Comment: See edit. If I use is_null() my code will always evaluate to false, because NULL is converted to empty string "".

Comment: Thanks for your effort, stupid me, strip_tags() actually stripped NULL to empty string in my sanitize function. That was last thing I should expected.