# Symfony2 and/or Doctrine2 does not respect the restrictions, how that can be possible?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-2.7

I have a project setup in top of Sonata Admin. I am experiencing something new and nonsense which is the first time I see. I have the entity `Media` (see definition down in the post) where you can see almost everything is not nullable, in fact if I check the DB schema I can see the `NOT NULL` constraint in columns as `$title`, `$titleHtml` and some other. I have a `MediaAdmin` controller (see definition down in the post). If I erase all the content in `title` and `titleHtml` and some other column and hit `Update` button, surprise I can save that entity and I ask myself, how? Where is the magic here? I am surprised and have not logic explanation but the problem is that this is wrong and should not happen, how do I fix it? I have something wrong in my code? Why happen this? I am using 2.7.5 and I am testing in DEV environment

**Media Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="media", options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci"})
 */
class Media
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use UploadTrait;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $media_type;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $titleHtml;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $descriptionHtml;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $thumbnail_url = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $media_url;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $media_code;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $inactive = false;

    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $useHtml = false;

    /**
     * @var Brand
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $brand;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Email", mappedBy="emailsMediaXref", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $mediaXrefMail;

    ....
}
```

**MediaAdmin Controller**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $image = $this->getSubject();
    $fileFieldOptions = array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Thumbnail');
    $fileMediaFieldOptions = array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Media File');

    if ($image && ($webPath = $image->getThumbnailUrl())) {
        $fileFieldOptions['help'] = 'Thumbnail: <img src="'.$webPath.'" class="admin-preview img-rounded img-responsive"/>';
        $fileMediaFieldOptions['help'] = 'Type: '.$image->getMediaType().'<br/>Name: '.$image->getMediaUrl();
    }

    $formMapper
        ->with('Information', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
            ->add('title', null, array(
                'label' => 'Title (text format)'
            ))
            ->add('titleHtml', 'ckeditor', array(
                'config_name' => 'default_config',
                'label' => 'Title (HTML format)'
            ))
            ->add('description', null, array(
                'label' => 'Description (text format)'
            ))
            ->add('descriptionHtml', 'ckeditor', array(
                'config_name' => 'default_config',
                'label' => 'Description (HTML format)',
                'attr' => array(
                    'row' => 5

            )))
            ->add('useHtml', null, array('required' => false))
            ->add('inactive', null, array('required' => false))
        ->end()
        ->with('Brand', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
            ->add('brand', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'btn_add' => 'Add',      //Specify a custom label
                    'btn_list' => 'Select',     //which will be translated
                    'btn_delete' => false,             //or hide the button.
                    ), array(
                    'placeholder' => 'No Brand selected',
            ))
        ->end()
        ->with('Media', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
            ->add('file', 'file', $fileFieldOptions)
            ->add('media_file', 'file', $fileMediaFieldOptions)
            ->add('media_type')
            ->add('media_code')
        ->end();
}
```

**EDIT 1: Test 1**

I have change the following line of code:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    protected $title;
```

to this:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $title;
```

then I run the following command and get the result as show below:

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

And then I tried to update the same by leaving the column `title` blank and I can see this as result on the query:

```
UPDATE media SET title = ?, titleHtml = ?, description = ?, descriptionHtml = ?, media_code = ?, updatedAt = ? WHERE id = ? [null,"sdfsdfsd",null,null,null,"2015-10-22 21:07:25",12]
```

I still not getting where is the problem and why that is allowed, any?

Comment: Null is not the same as a blank string.

Comment: @Cerad what's the difference and how this can be avoid?

Comment: Are you really asking for the difference between nulls and blank strings?  Interesting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sin

Comment: @Cerad after read the docs you point me I still not getting why the query still being executed and that is allowed, can you point me on the right direction?

Comment: @Cerad [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118957/insert-dont-work-with-not-null-but-update-does-why/118965#118965) is the answer to my problem was bad MariaDB `SQL_MODE` configuration thx anyway