# Any difference between init a member varible with null or not?

Tags: php

Example A:

```
class F {
  private $f = null;
}
```

Example B:

```
class F {
  private $f;
}
```

Any different between those two classes?

Comment: Absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between these two variable both of consider as `null`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Expression     | gettype()  | empty()  | is_null()  | isset()  | boolean  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $f = null;       | NULL       | TRUE     | TRUE       | FALSE    | FALSE    |
| $f;              | NULL       | TRUE     | TRUE       | FALSE    | FALSE    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is from @RexM [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sin)

> null is a special placeholder value in the programming language that literally means "nothing". It's not 0, it's not an empty string, it's nothing. There is no value in memory being pointed to. An empty string, on the other hand, is still a string object, just a very short one :)

Comment: What's the point in answering a question that you know it's a duplicate? Just flag the question accordingly.