# Why empty string not working but null works perfectly?

Tags: php, string, null

I just want to make a GET request in php and here is my requirement,

URL: http://localhost/test.php?firstName=Sagar&secondName=Gautam

Expected Output: Hi Sagar Gautam

URL: http://localhost/test.php

Expected Output: Hi Guest

Here is the code

**test.php**

```
<?php 
    $firstName = $_GET['firstName'];
    $secondName = $_GET['secondName'];

    $response = '';

    if($firstName!='' && $secondName!='')
    {
        $response = "Hi ".$firstName.' '.$secondName;
    }
    else
    {
        $response = "Hi Guest";
    }

    echo $response;
?>
```

Above code doesn't work but when I change empty string to null in if statement like this

```
if($firstName!=null && $secondName!=null)
```

then everything works perfectly.

I've already visited this question: [In PHP, what is the differences between NULL and setting a string to equal 2 single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sin) but don't get idea why above code not work with empty string.

If somebody explain whats going wrong, it will be great.

Comment: `''` and `null` are different because `''` still has a value. `firstName` and `secondName` parameters are assigned a blank, whereas when there are no parameters at all, they are set as `null`

Comment: @alimbaronia When no parameter are sent in request then those values are null or empty string ?

Comment: they are considered `null`

Comment: Which means if route like http://localhost/test.php?firstName=&secondName= will work for the above code ?

Comment: You can do
`if(($firstName!=null || $firstname=='')&& ($secondName!=null || $secondName==''))` to catch both cases

Comment: Okay, I've just got confused before now everything is clear, thank you

Comment: The code you pasted actually performs exactly as you want it to. When acessing it without first and last name (both of them) I see Hi guest, and if I add the parameters, I see Hi name

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check `isset()` the `$_GET` variables

```
$firstName = isset($_GET['firstName']) ? $_GET['firstName'] : '';
$secondName = isset($_GET['secondName']) ?  $_GET['firstName']: '';
```

We always get the not null value.

Just a small note: `isset` will take care null case for you too. `isset($null_value) -> false`

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but... it is not, actually better. There is no difference. Checking for equivalence against empty string or null makes no difference. BTW, OP's code works perfectly already. try it.

Comment: If directly gets `$firstName = $_GET['firstName'];`, it will throw error" `Undefined index: firstName` when there is no paramter `firstName`.

Comment: oh, right, the notice. ok, fair enough. maybe you can mention the new null coalesce operator `$firstName = $_GET['firstName'] ?? '';`.

Comment: And from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sin. `$y = null; isset($y)  ->  false
echo $y    ->  ""`

Comment: Thanks, I am fairly aware of these, I was not thinking of the notice for undefined index. In this case, as OP was already using that, they did not seem to care about the notice anyway. That being said, that's not really what they asked...

Comment: I see. One more thing I want to say: `isset` will take care `null` case for you too. `isset($null_value) -> false`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if($firstName!=='' && $secondName!=='')
```

Hope This Help

Comment: Because If you use != for the operator it will check only if $a or $b is not equal in this case $firstName is containing null not ' ' so that's why it return false but when you use !== it will also check the type so it will return True CMIIW