# Condition always returning true

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check if email is required and if yes,check email is not null ,Whenever i am checking this condition the variable validation_ok  is always returning 1 as the value . Even if the condition satisfies, every time it is returning true.

This is my code:

```
if ($validations['customer_reg_email'] == 'required' && $email=='') 
            {
                        $validation_ok = false;
                        $status        = 'Please provide a valid email';
                    } 
                  else 
                      {
                        $validation_ok = true;
                    }
```

I would appreciate your help regarding this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Try checking `$validations['customer_reg_email']` and `$email` by echoing them out and see what it's actually checking.

Comment: You say you want to check for null, but then your code checks for an empty string. `null` is not the same as "declared but contains no characters" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/624927/5947043). Therefore, `$email==''` and `$email == null` are different tests. Do `var_dump($email);` as a debugging step on the line before the `if`, to see what `$email` _really_ contains.

Comment: I tried ,email is null and the value 'customer_reg_email' is required still 'validation_ok ' is true

Comment: @ADyson i have also checked with $email==null, still getting the same result

Comment: Ok then, do the var_dump I suggested, and find out what is really in the variable.

Comment: Also check that `vallidations['customer_reg_email']` really contains the string 'required'` or not.

Comment: @ADyson this is what var_dump returns 
string(0) "" also validations['customer_reg_email'] is required

Comment: Maybe email = 'null' your check must be $email == 'null' or if email is NULL your check will be $email === NULL; but better check with empty().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much better to check your email with **empty()** and check what you have with **var_dump()** function.

```
var_dump($validations['customer_reg_email']);
echo "\n";
var_dump($email);
echo "\n";
$validation_ok = TRUE;
if($validations['customer_reg_email'] == 'required' and empty($email)){
   $validation_ok = FALSE;
   $status = 'Please provide a valid email';
}
```