# PHP array split into custom sentence?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array and I want to split it into a custom sentence.

```
  $array = array('apple','blue','red','green');
```

I want the output below:

```
  apple
  apple blue
  apple blue red
  apple blue red green
```

Comment: That’s rather the opposite of _splitting_, you want to _combine_ the array elements, to form some new output. What have you tried? Should be simple, using two nested for loops …

Comment: you could use a basic [concatenation](https://3v4l.org/YMBKt) cycling your array elements

Answer (score 1):

You could try this simple solution

```
$array = array('apple','blue','red','green');
$sentence = "";
foreach($array as $key) {
  if($sentence === ""){
    $sentence = $key;
  }
  else{
    $sentence = $sentence." ".$key;
  }
  echo $sentence;
  echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: Foreach is more efficient than for loop. Upvoting.

Comment: `if($sentence == null)`? When will `$sentence` ever be `null`? Wouldn't it make more sense to use strict comparison to what you manually assigned, `=== ''`?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes and no. we are comparing is strings, and an empty string can be evaluated as "null". your suggestion is more strict, mine is a bit more loose. you can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624922/in-php-what-is-the-differences-between-null-and-setting-a-string-to-equal-2-sin

Comment: Code is clearer when it's explicit. There is no need for a loose comparison since you know exactly what you should be comparing to.

Comment: Edited the code, made it more explicit using your suggestion @El_Vanja

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple lightweight solution

```
    $array = array('apple','blue','red','green');
    $str = '';
    foreach($array as $item) {
        $str = $str . ' ' . $item;
        echo(ltrim($str) . '<br>');
    }
```

Comment: The only minor issue is that there will be a leading space here.

Comment: @El_Vanja Yeah thats true, can be solved by just adding a ltrim to it I guess

Answer (score 1):

Use for-loop with [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to Extract a slice of the array each time, And use `implode(glue, pieces)` to join the values of the array with a space.

```php
$array = array('apple','blue','red','green');
for ($i=1; $i <= count($array) ; $i++) { 
    echo implode(' ', array_slice($array, 0, $i))."</br>";
}
```

**Prints:**

```
apple
apple blue
apple blue red
apple blue red green
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple

```js
$array = array('apple','blue','red','green');
$new = "";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++) {
  for($j=0; $j<=$i; $j++){
    $new .= $array[$j]." ";
  }
  $new .= "<br>";
}
echo $new;
```

Comment: it's not very efficient to use `sizeof()` in your for loop. Also, one `foreach()` loop should suffice.